# Sticky navigation bar only works with a variable

Tags: javascript

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .header {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 30px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }

    #navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    #navbar a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }

    #navbar a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }

    .content {
      padding: 16px;
    }

    .sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .sticky + .content {
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="header">
      <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
      <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar">
      <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
      <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    </div>
 </body>
```

This code was from [W3CSchools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky).

Looking at the javascript code at the bottom, you can see the variable `sticky`, which is used store the `offsetTop` of the navbar. However if I switch `sticky` to `navbar.offsetTop`, everything just won't work. So..

```
if (window.pageYOffset >= navbar.offsetTop)
```

won't work unless I have it as a variable.

I am looking for an explanation to why not setting the `offsetTop` as a variable isn't working. Any answers/suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's because the `navbar.offsetTop` changes when the bar moves, so you need the initial `offsetTop`

Comment: Add some debugging output to observe what's happening.  In the "working" version, do `console.log(sticky)` inside the function.  In the "non-working" version, do `console.log(navbar.offsetTop)` inside the function.  What is the difference between the two?

Comment: @Pete That explanation clears up a lot. Thank you.

Comment: In modern CSS you can just do this with [`position:sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) no Javascript, etc. also [bootstrap has a sticky class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/position/) that includes polyfils for old browsers. So there should be no need to use JS at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event listeners function is what causes the browser to watch the offset type

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
```

since you declared a variable with the offset type outside of the function

```
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
```

This variable is not effected when you scroll and is set to what it was initially

calling just `navbar.offsetTop` inside an event listener will always change when you scroll because its being updated on scroll